# Video plays in Opera but the skin is not the one defined in options (and it doesn't play in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, video.js, dynamically-generated

I am developing a page with a popup to show the video selected.
I use Bootstrap and the video is shown in a modal dialog.

The problem is that, even if I define the skin as vjs-tech (or the default - video-js vjs-default-skin), the one which is shown is the white one.
In Firefox, the skin is shown but the browser don't play the video.

The video is in h264 and the audio is in aac formats (it's a stream).

The web page code, for the modal popup is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalAstraPlayer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog videocenter" id="videocontainer">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <div style="width:560px; height:340px;" id="videoplayer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript code (which generates the modal content for the video), is:

```
    var video;

    var videoaddress = document.getElementById("videoaddress").value;
    channelname = row.output;
    var n = channelname.lastIndexOf('/');
    var result = channelname.substring(n + 1);
    var videotoshow = videoaddress + "/" + result; // this is the video address...

    var mainDiv = document.getElementById('videoplayer');

    var divContainer = document.createElement('div');
    divContainer.class = 'example-video-container';
    divContainer.style.display = 'inline-block';
    divContainer.id = "videodiv";
    mainDiv.appendChild(divContainer);

    // Create Video Player
    video = document.createElement('video');
    video.id = 'vid2';
    video.width = 560;
    video.height = 315;
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.controls = true;
    video.muted = false;
    video.preload = 'auto';
    video.poster = "../images/loading.jpg";
    video.setAttribute("example_option", "true");
    video.setAttribute("playbackRates", "[1, 1.5, 2]");
    //video.setAttribute("controlspreload", "none");
    video.setAttribute("class", "vjs-tech"); //video-js vjs-tech video-js vjs-default-skin");

    function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type)
    {
        var source = document.createElement('source');
        source.src = src;
        source.type = type;
        element.appendChild(source);
    }

    addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mp4');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.58A01E, mp4a.40.2"');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001E, mp4a.40.2"');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4v.20.8, mp4a.40.2"');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4v.20.240, mp4a.40.2"');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mp2t');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mpeg');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/msvideo');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/3gpp');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/3gpp2');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/avi');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/mpeg');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/msvideo');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'video/quicktime');
    //addSourceToVideo(video, videotoshow, 'application/octet-stream');

    console.log("Video Creation End");
    console.log("Paragraph Started");

    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Video PlayBack Not Supported";
    video.appendChild(paragraph);
    divContainer.appendChild(video);

    $("#div_video_html5_api").show(); // Not necessary?

    video.load();
    video.play();

    $('#myModalAstraPlayer').modal('show');

    jQuery('#myModalAstraPlayer').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e)
    {

    });

    jQuery('#myModalAstraPlayer').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e)
    {
        video.pause();
        videojs(video).dispose();

        try
        {
            document.getElementById("videodiv").remove();
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    });

    var myVideo = document.getElementById("vid2");

    // disable right-click over video...
    if (myVideo.addEventListener)
    {
        myVideo.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    }
    else
    {
        myVideo.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function()
        {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
```

Anybody can help with some example code or a clue about the problem?

Opera popup:
[image: Opera popup]

Firefox Popup:
[image: Firefox Popup]

Comment: Where's the html that contains the 'video' tag???

Comment: It's dynamically generated by the video = document.createElement('video'); and subsequently populated with the elements that are relative to videojs.

Comment: Ah yes..I see that now.  So, my thought is that you need an additional  token in the class attribute there.  Try including a token of 'video-js'.  [ On my working example, my class attribute has 2 tokens:  class="video-js  vjs-default-skin"  Tokens are separated by 'space' character. ]